# Gcc, WinAPI and 1250

Tags: winapi, gcc, unicode, ascii, cp1250

Im from Poland, It is easy to me to write

```
char* text = "Wół się cięć że goń ów stan"l
```

with polish chars (in ascii strings) - 
I checked and it is encoded as Windows-1250 code page.
When i use those strigs in winapi (like in SetTitle
function) it works okay.. Seems thet winapi and gcc
treats it all right..

One thing i am not sure is if this way produced 
winapi app will work okay when distributed on all 
windows systems around the world..

Does maybe some acknowledge or deny it (and provide 
more information)?

tnx

Comment: It will not. It will only work correctly if the target computer runs your program with the Windows-1250 codepage equivalent set. While I think you can set it on your program yourself, you should switch to writing programs using Unicode APIs and wide-character strings (`L"..."`) instead (unless you still need Windows 9x support for whatever reason).

Comment: how set? type it as an answer and i will accept that - Though could you say which machines will not have 1250 set? Rusiia? China?

Comment: That's not an ASCII string. It's an ANSI string. ANSI was all the rage, 20 years ago. Today we have Unicode, and all NT-based versions of Windows support it.

Comment: but im lazy and it works (it is handy as it is pure-8-bit such as ascii and has european basic charset)... I only want to know where my app will nt work [here it works perfectly simple and perfectly well - i just type and i see, all 8-bit chard in c to which im very accustomed)

Comment: if you are really planing to distribute your application world wide, you have no choice to convert it to unicode, lazy or not, you will end by getting to use it.

Comment: well maybe - but the answer i seek now is where this 1250 compiled app will not work correctly

Comment: The locales that use code page 1250 are Albania, Croatia, Czeska, Hungary, Poland, Romania, Slovakia and Slovenia. Everywhere else in the world (and on any machines not configured with that locale, eg servers which commonly run en_US), your program will produce the wrong text. ANSI code pages are a sad hangover of a time long gone and shouldn't be used in anything new.

Comment: Since you name *"laziness"* as your motivation for using ANSI codepages, had you actually considered what a Unicode implementation would look like? Hint: `const wchar_t text[] = L"Wół się cięć że goń ów stan";` (btw. the code you posted is the precursor to undefined behavior). Stop being lazy, where it counts, and read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: alright, though it would work in english based countries, if 1250 do not shows ok there what code page they will see?

Comment: this example do not compile ` error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence`

Comment: I'm guessing the answer will be the same as when using MSVC: [1] Use the wide version of the Windows APIs (define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`), [2] use a wide character string, and [3] make sure the compiler and your text editor agree on the source file encoding. I think both MSVC and GCC can handle UTF-8 with BOM.

Answer (score 0):

This text will NOT be displayed correct on most Windows machines all around the world. Default encoding for US is Windows-1252.

Windows has a "language for non-Unicode applications" (see screenshot), which defines encoding for applications like yours. In my case it will be Windows-1251 and characters specific to Polish alphabet will be changed with Cyrillic letters and text will be completely unreadable.

[image: Windows 10 screenshot]